# Best software to use to program a Pycom FiPy?

Tags: micropython, pycom

The two recommended editors for a pymakr project are:

1. Visual Studio Code alongside the Pymakr plugin, which flat-out doesn't work for me (and based on the predominately 1-star reviews it has, I'm not the only one).
2. Atom, which hasn't worked with the newest version of Node JS (a requirement for the pycom) in over 3 years.

And yet, I can't find anyone talking about alternatives. What do you use to program your pycom? Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

All the v2.x.x versions of pymakr seems to suck. Downgrade to v1.1.18 and good to go with vscode.